# Bug on second slide of carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I've been spending the last 8 hours trying to build my own carousel, I am new at jquery.
So I have a bug on the second slide.

If you see when I click on the second next, the prev button should appear, but instead it only appears in the 2nd click.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sliderWidth     = 300; // Give the size of the window
    var sliderV         = $('#slide-wrap-vertical'); // Assigns the container that has all the sectiosn that will be scrolled vertically
    var sliderCount     = $('#slide-wrap-vertical').children().size(); // Gets the size of the vertical slider    
    var sliderHeight    = sliderCount * sliderWidth; // Takes the height of the slider

    $('#slide-wrap-vertical').css('height', sliderHeight); // assigns the height
    //$('a.temp').text(sliderHeight);    

    showHideDirection();

    $('a.nav-top-prev').on('click',function () {

        $('#slide-wrap-vertical > div').animate({
            'top': '+=' + sliderWidth + 'px'
        }, 500);
        showHideDirection();

    });

    $('a.nav-top-next').on('click', function () {
        $('#slide-wrap-vertical > div').animate({
            'top': '-=' + sliderWidth + 'px'
        }, 500);
        showHideDirection();

    });


    function showHideDirection() {

        $(sliderV).children().each(function(){ // Checks all the children of the vertical carousel          

            if ($(this).position().top == 0) {
                var index = $(this).index();

                $('a.nav-top-prev').toggle(index!==0);
                $('a.nav-top-next').toggle(index!==sliderCount-1);
            }

        });
    }


});
```

I added the jsfiddle as well if you want to see the functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/Dethdoll/WkFVs/12/

Answer (score 3):

The animate call will be asynchronous with the code that follows it, so the subsequent lines of code will start executing *before* the animation is complete. So `showHideDirection` still sees your position as being at the first slide, immediately after you've clicked it only once. You need to have that called only after the animation is complete.

The way to do this is to assign `showHideDirection` as the callback argument of `animate()` rather than calling it as a subsequent line of code.  The [.animate() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) names this the `complete` parameter:

```
$('a.nav-top-next').on('click', function () {
    $('#slide-wrap-vertical > div').animate({
        'top': '-=' + sliderWidth + 'px'
    }, 500,  showHideDirection);
});
```

*note*: the documentation lists `complete` as the 4th paramter, but as the 3rd named parameter (`easing`) requires a string value, if you pass in a function name instead in that place, jQuery will realize that you are skipping the `easing` parameter, and interpret it as the `complete` parameter.

*more notes:*

Well done for a jQuery beginner. A few pointers:

- A widely used convention is to prepend variable-names that hold jQuery objects
  with a `$`,  e.g.: `var $sliderV = $('#slide-wrap-vertical');`This adds semantics / helps to keep track of what's what, particularly for function argument-names it shows that you are *expecting* a jQuery object passed in
- You set up `sliderV` at the outermost (non-global) scope, so it will be available anywhere in your code, but you recapture the jQuery object 2 more times instead of just re-using sliderV. This is extra work for the javascript engine. In this case the difference will be neglegible, but as you get on with bigger jQuery projects, you'll need to be stingier, so better start with the good habbits now.
- Your method of tracking which slide is "on" relies on an un-reliable artifact of the interface (finding a slide at vertical-position of 0). What if you, say, decide to add a buffer around the slide frame by adding a margin-top to it? Now no slide will ever be at 0 when it settles. One alternative would be to set up an index variable as 0 at the beginning of your code, then increment/decrement the index as the user navigates forward or back, change this value *immediately* when a nav is clicked, and hide the prev/next button depending on the value of the index (e.g. hide prev if index is 0). Now you're not dependent on the animation completing for your test, either.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I added the call to the function inside the animation but not like that. Thank you

Comment: I really appreciate your notes. Thanks this gives me more tools and knowledge to complete this project.